# Source Connector adds Quotes Around JSON Field

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I use confluent Source Connector to copy data from Postgres to Kafka

The following is the table I want to be copied to Kafka:

```
CREATE TABLE public.format_ts_v
(
    alerts json,
    updated timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
)
```

alerts field is a json with the following format

```
{"alerts":[{"timedate":4587052516256796700,"elementName":"pariatur commodo","description":"ex eiusmod consectetur"}]
```

I create a stream

```
CREATE STREAM alerts_stream_json_array 
      (alerts ARRAY<STRUCT<
            timedate INT, 
            elementName VARCHAR,
            description VARCHAR>>, 
       updated INT) 
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='cdc1_format_ts_v', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

And use the following to view the data

```
SELECT EXPLODE(alerts)->timedate AS timedate,
       EXPLODE(alerts)->elementName AS elementName,
       EXPLODE(alerts)->description AS description
FROM   alerts_stream_json_array 
EMIT CHANGES;
```

If I insert a message directly to Kafka without the source connector it works great

```
/kafkacat/kafkacat/kafkacat -b 127.0.0.1:9092 -P -t cdc1_format_ts_v <<EOF
{"alerts":{"timedate":4587052516256796700,"elementName":"pariatur commodo","description":"ex eiusmod consectetur"}}
EOF
```

But when the data is inserted with the source connector an extra quote is added to the json string and the ksql select no longer works

```
{"alerts":"[{\x5C"timedate\x5C":4587052516256796700,"elementName\x5C":\x5C"pariatur commodo\x5C",\x5C"description\x5C":\x5C"ex eiusmod consectetur\x5C"}]","updated":1594909653789}
```

How can I avoid the quote around the json?  Can I get it to work even with the quote?

Thanks

Comment: May help to add details of the connector config, as this is where the issue seems to be.

Comment: Also, how are you checking the format of the data in the topic?  Are you using a standard consumer, KafkaCat, ksql PRINT?